# Retrofit: Could not locate ResponseBody converter for

Tags: java, web-service, retrofit

Estou trabalhando em um sistema e preciso do [Retrofit2](http://square.github.io/retrofit/) (com Spring Boot) mas não estou conseguindo.

Segue o fonte e o erro.

```
@JsonIgnoreProperties({"codibge", "codestado"}) 
public class CEP {

private String cep;
private String logradouro;
private String complemento;
private String bairro;
private String cidade;
private String estado;
```

---

```
public interface HelloService {
    @GET("{cep}")
    Call<CEP> getEndereco(@Path("cep") String cep);
}
```

---

```
public class HelloController {

private HelloService helloService;
private static final Logger logger = LoggerFactory.getLogger(App.class);

public HelloController() {
    Retrofit retrofit = new Retrofit.Builder()
        .baseUrl("http://api.postmon.com.br/v1/cep/")
        .build();       
    helloService = retrofit.create(HelloService.class);
}

public void getEndereco(String cep) {
    Response<CEP> response = null;
    try {
        response = helloService.getEndereco(cep).execute();
        if (response.isSuccessful()) {
            logger.info("Sucesso...");
        } else {
            logger.error("Erro...");
        }
    } catch (IOException e) {
        logger.error(e.toString());
    }
}
```

---

```
@SpringBootApplication
public class App {

    private static final Logger log = LoggerFactory.getLogger(App.class);

    public static void main(String args[]) {
        SpringApplication.run(App.class);
        HelloController hello = new HelloController();
        hello.getEndereco("82560435");
    }
}
```

Quando testo retorna o seguinte erro:

```
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Unable to create converter for class br.com.hello.api.CEP
for method HelloService.getEndereco
at retrofit2.ServiceMethod$Builder.methodError(ServiceMethod.java:755)
at retrofit2.ServiceMethod$Builder.createResponseConverter(ServiceMethod.java:741)
at retrofit2.ServiceMethod$Builder.build(ServiceMethod.java:172)
at retrofit2.Retrofit.loadServiceMethod(Retrofit.java:170)
at retrofit2.Retrofit$1.invoke(Retrofit.java:147)
at com.sun.proxy.$Proxy72.getEndereco(Unknown Source)
at br.com.hello.api.HelloController.getEndereco(HelloController.java:29)
at br.com.hello.api.App.main(App.java:17)
Caused by: java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Could not locate ResponseBody converter for class br.com.hello.api.CEP.
Tried:
* retrofit2.BuiltInConverters
at retrofit2.Retrofit.nextResponseBodyConverter(Retrofit.java:351)
at retrofit2.Retrofit.responseBodyConverter(Retrofit.java:313)
at  retrofit2.ServiceMethod$Builder.createResponseConverter(ServiceMethod.java:739)
... 6 more
```

O que estou fazendo de errado?

Comment: O Retrofit trata as respostas como entidade, é necessario um conversor, pode usar o Gson ou o JacksonJson, para cada biblioteca vc faz o seu devido mapeamento

Comment: Neste exemplo do CEP funcionou, vou tentar agora com o FCM acredito que também vai dar certo. Obrigado

Answer (score 4, accepted):

O Retrofit por si só não faz [de]serialização de JSON. Ele delega isso a converters. Então, ao construir o objeto Retrofit, você deve passar o converter de sua preferência. Eles dão suporte ao Jackson, que é o padrão do SpringBoot:

```
Retrofit retrofit = new Retrofit.Builder()
    .baseUrl("http://api.postmon.com.br/v1/cep/")
    .addConverterFactory(JacksonConverterFactory.create())
    .build();
```

Também dá pra passar um object mapper, caso você queira compartilhar as configurações do SpringBoot:

```
.addConverterFactory(JacksonConverterFactory.create(myObjectMapper))
```

Lembrando que será necessário adicionar a dependência:

```
<dependency>
  <groupId>com.squareup.retrofit2</groupId>
  <artifactId>converter-jackson</artifactId>
  <version>2.4.0/version>
</dependency>
```

Comment: Perfeito... Funcionou.  Obrigado